# implementing IEnumerable<T> and IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() can not be public, why?

Tags: c#, .net, enumerator, ienumerator

> To implement an interface member, the corresponding member of the
>   implementing class must be public. source: [Interfaces (C# Programming
>   Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx)

I know it works if its private, but i would like to understand why it can not be public ?

[image: must be private interface member implementation]

Comment: When you use the interface name to explicitly implement a member of the interface the member will have the same access as the interface itself and cannot be modified. Public interfaces have public members. So you can say `public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()`, implicitly implementing the interface or `IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When implemented explicitly interface methods are public by default and that's why you cannot use access modifiers.

A quote from msdn.com :

> When a member is explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through
>   a class instance, but only through an instance of the interface
>   (which is public by default)

source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

P.S. 
Difference between implicit and explicit implementation :

```
interface MyInterface
{
   void MyMethod();
}

class A : MyInterface  // Implicit implementation
{
   public void MyMethod () { ... }
}

class B: MyInterface   // Explicit implementation
{
   void MyInterface.MyMethod () { ... }
}
```

Comment: Additional Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx (The part where the class implements two different Paint methods) and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx (`When a member is explicitly implemented, it cannot be accessed through a class instance,`). This is used in the .net Framework e.g. in Arrays which implement `IList.Count` explicitly (hence it's not visible on an array directly)

Comment: Thank you. So implemented explicitly means, implemented anything the interface you are implementing inherits.

Comment: Close but implicit implementation it's when you implement interface method on a class without pointing explicitly to an interface name.  I've updated my answer to show the difference.

Comment: I think the comments should be on the methods. Your example implies you must choose to implement the class (in it's entirety) implicitly or explicitly .  There's nothing stopping you from implementing part of an interface implicitly and the other part explicitly